# Why does the filter function in matlab get different results from the IIR filters using direct form?

Tags: filters

I have 6 first order filters, each one has 2 coefficients (B(x1,x1), B(x2,x2) for the numerator and A(y1,y1),A(y2,y2) for the denominator).

```
B = [0.6 0 ; 1 0.3 ; 1 -1; 1 -1 ; 1 -1; 1 -1]; % b(1,1) ajustado para 0.6
A = [1 -0.2025 ; 1 -0.2025 ; 1 -0.9860 ; 1 -0.9097 ; 1 -0.9973 ; 1 -0.9973];

[H1,f1] = freqz([B(1,1) B(1,2)] ,[A(1,1) A(1,2)],512,48000);
[H2,f2] = freqz([B(2,1) B(2,2)] ,[A(2,1) A(2,2)],512,48000);
[H3,f3] = freqz([B(3,1) B(3,2)] ,[A(3,1) A(3,2)],512,48000);
[H4,f4] = freqz([B(4,1) B(4,2)] ,[A(4,1) A(4,2)],512,48000);
[H5,f5] = freqz([B(5,1) B(5,2)] ,[A(5,1) A(5,2)],512,48000);
[H6,f6] = freqz([B(6,1) B(6,2)] ,[A(6,1) A(6,2)],512,48000);

mag = abs( H1.*H2.*H3.*H4.*H5.*H6); % pus um ajuste de 0.5

magdb = 20*log10(mag);
semilogx(f2,magdb)

ylim([-70 40])
title('Digital implementation of the A-weighting filter (fs = 48 kHz)')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Gain(dB)')
grid on
```

This is the transfer function i obtain (ignore the title):

[image]

And here are all the poles (each pole corresponds to one first order filter):

```
P =

   0.202500000000000


P =

   0.202500000000000


P =

   0.986000000000000


P =

   0.909700000000000


P =

   0.997300000000000


P =

   0.997300000000000
```

Every pole is inside the unit circle.

This is the code and frequency response of the third first order filter:

```
%%% H3
figure()
mag = abs( H3);
magdb = 20*log(mag);
semilogx(f1,magdb);

ylim([-70 40])
title('Digital implementation of the A-weighting filter (fs = 48 kHz)')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Gain(dB)')
```

[image]

Using the filter function i obtain the following for a 10000Hz sin wave:

```
t = linspace(0,1,fs);
x = sin(2*pi*10000*t);

y = filter([B(3,1) B(3,2)],[A(3,1) A(3,2)],x);

figure()
plot(t,x)
hold on
plot(t,y)
legend('Input Data','Filtered Data')
```

[image]

This is exactly what i'm expecting.

But now if i use the IIR Filter coeficcent using the past values i get something different:

```
x=[0 0];
y=[0 0];

t = linspace(0,1,fs);

yy = zeros(1,fs);


for c= 1:fs
x(1) = sin(2*pi*10000*t(c));


y(1) = (1/A(3,1))*(B(3,1)*x(1) + B(3,2)*x(2) + A(3,2)*y(2) ); 

yy(c) = y(1);
  % update x and y data vectors
  for i = 2:-1:1
    x(i+1) = x(i); % store xi
    y(i+1) = y(i); % store yi
  end
  
 
end

figure()
plot(t,yy)
```

[image]

Why does this happen? How can i get the same response as the filter function?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `y(1)` equation should be

```
y(1) = (1/A(3,1))*(B(3,2)*x(1) + B(3,1)*x(2) + A(3,1)*y(2) );
```

then I get

[image: Plot with equation change.]

Note also, the update should just be

```
x(2) = x(1)
y(2) = y(1)
```

otherwise the `x` and `y` matrices grow to be $3 \times 1$ after the first time through the inner `for` loop.

Comment: I agree with the inner loop part, but if i change the coefficients the way u did it i always get amplitude 1 even for low frequencies, that should not happen